# How To Get The Person Who Banned In Discord.py

Tags: python, time, discord, discord.py

As the title says, my question is, **is there a way to get the User object of who banned someone?**
It may be something like this:

```py
async def someone_got_banned(banner, banned, reason, time):

   print(f"{banner} has just banned {banned} (The time is {time}), and their reason for doing so is {reason}")
```

Comment: @Ironkey Can you show that in use? Edit: Nvm they just deleted the comment, sorry if I did smth wrong

Comment: sorry, theres a built in function already: on_member_ban() and on_guild_remove() might work -->

look at the docs here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html | atm i dont have access to discord so I couldn't test it.

Comment: @Ironkey Yes, I have seen it somewhere, thanks though, but I think it only shows **who was banned**, yet not **who actually banned**.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, using `Guild.audit_logs()`

Below is the revised code

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, member):
    logs = await guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban).flatten()
    channel = guild.get_channel(CHANNEL_ID)
    logs = logs[0]
    if logs.target == member:
        await channel.send(f'{logs.user} has just banned {logs.target} (The time is {logs.created_at}), and their reason for doing so is {logs.reason}')
```

Comment: Thanks! (Sorry for being late to answer btw)                          What's up with *.flatten()* in line 3 ("logs=...") ?

Comment: I meant to ask why do we need it, what's the point of that method, what that does.

One more question, wouldn't the result of the *if logs.target==member* always be True beacuse the first ban in the audit log would directly be caught to *on_member_ban_*?

Comment: `if logs.target==member` to be sure that its that member, during mass ban it can be different if your bot take some time to query the audit logs
flatten() is to convert the AsyncIterator to a list, if we didn't use flatten() we would need fo to use `async for x in logs:`

Comment: I get it, appreciate your reply :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`on_member_ban()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_ban) event but it only has `guild` and `user` parameters. You can't get the reason but you can get the time with `datetime` module. Here is an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime
@client.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, member):
    await guild.text_channels[0].send(f'{member} banned at {datetime.now()}.')
```

In this code, it'll send the message to the first text channel. If you want to change the channel, you can define-get a channel with [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get).

```
from datetime import datetime
@client.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, member):
    channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name='the channel name that the message will send')
    await channel.send(f'{member} banned at {datetime.now()}.')
```

Comment: Thanks, and sorry I saw your reply late

Comment: Is there a way to get the ID of a channel via its name, or place in a category without using *discord.utils*?

Comment: You can iterate through all the channels in the guild and check their names but this is a little bit inefficient. For example:
`channel = [channel for channel in guild.text_channels if channel.name=='channel name']`.

Comment: Hmm, OK. I get it now. Well, I should get used to utils. But, let's say, if there are more efficient ways -in some particular things-  in the other one (not utils, classic) as well, how to use the efficiency of each? Is there a way to use both classic commands and utils commands at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by classic and 
"use both classic commands and utils commands at the same time"?

Comment: Aren't there discord.py commands work the same with utils at some point? I mean them. Like, if I'm not wrong, `await message.channel.send` and `await ctx.send` will do the same thing (not counting on_message difference)

and by "use both classic commands and utils commands at the same time" i ask whether or not can I use those them in the same program, when one needed use that, and vice versa.

Comment: Utils and sending messages are totally diffirent things. `utils.get`, `find` gets, finds you a member, role, guild, channel etc. You can't compare these things. If you want to learn more about utility functions, you can look at the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#utility-functions).

Comment: Thanks, I thought ctx commands are also a part of these and I ddidn't really know much about them either. I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

```py
@bot.event
async def on_member_ban(guild, user):
    logs = [log async for log in guild.audit_logs(limit=1, action=discord.AuditLogAction.ban)]
    logs = logs[0]
    print('logs: ', logs) # printing the logs
    print(logs.user) # the admin the banned the user
    print(log.target) # the user that got 
    print(logs.created_at) # ban time
    print(logs.reason) # reason, it will return None if the admin didn't state a reason
```